# How to get the absolute height difference between the sub-trees of every node in a binary tree?

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I need to take a binary search tree, get the value of every node as well as the absolute height difference between the subtrees of every node in it, so as to then put both in a priority queue, the former as a value and the latter as its associated priority.

I know the solution must be recursive in nature, but I'm having some serious trouble with actually getting to access every node in the tree to pass it back to the method that will calculate its height and so far the information I've found in books/online is not helping, or far well above my current level of knowledge (basic Java course). I'd appreciate all and any help you could provide.

The solution that seems to work the most so far was the first I tried where I just deleted the root before I was done with every iteration and so each time managed to pass the method a new value but that of course gave the tree a new shape (aside from completely deleting it in the end) and so, logically, altered the final results.

Here's the working bit of my code:

```js
              
           
     /*node format for reference:
  class nodo {
  int v;                 //node value
  ABBTDA izq, der;}      //left & right children    */


 public static ColaCPTDA arbolCP (ABBTDA a)
 {
  ColaCP ult = new ColaCP();   //creating Priority Queue
  ult.inicializarColaCP();            //& initializing it
  
  
  int totalI, totalD,total=0;    
  ABBTDA aux = new ABB();      //creating Binary Search Trees
  aux.inicializarArbol();         //& initializing them
  ABBTDA aux2 = new ABB();
  aux2.inicializarArbol();
  
  //calculating heights of each child of Root node          
  totalI = altura(a.hijoIzq());     //left child
  totalD = altura(a.hijoDer());     //right child
      
                //calculating the absolute difference 
                total = Math.abs(totalI -totalD);  
      
                //adding the root value and its associated priority calculated 
                //to the Priority Queue
  ult.agregar(a.raiz(), total); 
   
           
  return ult;  
  
 }
 
 
 
 
 public static int altura (ABBTDA a) {  //method to calculate tree height
   
  if (a.arbolVacio()) 
   return -1;
  else   
    return 1 + Math.max( altura( a.hijoIzq() ), altura( a.hijoDer() ) );
    
  }
```

Comment: "Here's the working bit of my code" - please post [mcve], and include test data. I would also recommend using names that will make the code easier to read rather than names like `ABBTDA`